# Wordpress - Custom Heading Block

Tags: wordpress, wordpress-gutenberg, gutenberg-blocks

So I've seen wordpress's heading block where you can choose what heading tag the title is, so h1, h3 etc.... I'm making my own custom gutenberg blocks and i'd like to implement this heading tag switch feature where you can dynamically change the h tag of the title within my custom block.

The only problem is it seems to be somewhat difficult to find out how this wordpress block functions. I can't seem to find any developer docs or github code or anything.

So my question is are there developer docs? or how does this heading block work? im not sure where to start.

Thanks.

Comment: https://developer.wordpress.org/block-editor/how-to-guides/block-tutorial/writing-your-first-block-type/

Comment: so i'm talking about this wordpress heading block in particular, i've already used this link and know the process of how to make blocks. just asking about this heading block. I can't find a github for it or in-details dev docs.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The docs for Gutenberg are pretty rough, but if you are willing to dig through the code you can usually find what you are looking for. Here is the [code that creates the heading level dropdown for the Heading block in Gutenberg](https://github.com/WordPress/gutenberg/blob/aa22cd7714bbbd63b95dd9cfab0a894cba6d5ec2/packages/block-library/src/heading/heading-level-dropdown.js).

And below is a simplified version of what the Heading block does.

Use a [`<Toolbar>`](https://github.com/WordPress/gutenberg/tree/trunk/packages/components/src/toolbar) component to select the heading tag:

```js
<Toolbar label={ __('Change heading tag', 'text-domain') }>
    <ToolbarGroup
        isCollapsed={ true }
        controls={ [
            {
                tag: 'h1',
                label: __('Heading 1', 'text-domain'),
            },
            {
                tag: 'h2',
                label: __('Heading 2', 'text-domain'),
            },
            {
                tag: 'h3',
                label: __('Heading 3', 'text-domain'),
            },
            {
                tag: 'h4',
                label: __('Heading 4', 'text-domain'),
            },
            {
                tag: 'h5',
                label: __('Heading 5', 'text-domain'),
            },
            {
                tag: 'h6',
                label: __('Heading 6', 'text-domain'),
            }
        ].map((tag) => {
            return {
                title: tag.label,
                isActive: headingTag === tag.tag,
                onClick: () => setAttributes({'headingTag': tag.tag}),
            }
        }) }
    />
</Toolbar>
```

Then in your edit/save function you can set the component tag with a [`<RichText>`](https://github.com/WordPress/gutenberg/tree/trunk/packages/block-editor/src/components/rich-text) component:

```js
<RichText
    tagName={ headingTag }
    value={ content }
    onChange={ value => setAttributes({content: value}) }
/>
```

Technically the `Heading` block uses an integer attribute called `level` for storing the `1`, `2`, `3`, etc. Then they create the heading level by prepending `h` to `level` attribute. The above example lets you use additional HTML tags if you want by storing the entire HTML tag name (e.g. `<p>`, `<div>`, etc.).

Comment: ye phil thanks this is along the lines what i was looking for with the github code, couldn't find it. and thanks for the example too. I'll comment if i run into any problems but thanks.

Comment: To the ToolBarGroup, I added `icon={ heading }` which requires `import { heading } from '@wordpress/icons';`